# How to use file instead of db?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, search, logging

My application have a lot of logs. Currently part of this logs I write into azure blob file, part of them into db. 
I need to use only file in blob or on machine. I need to have possibility querying and filtering rows of this file to find that I need. I don't need to use existing logs, I can create any predefined structure.
The reason why I don't want to use db is the cost of db, given the rapid growth in db size.
So, what is the best way to implement this?
I will be glad for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on **what** and **how** you are logging, application logs are typically written using the `System.Diagnostic.Trace` class. The log level and storage (file or blob) can be configured through the portal. Read more about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log).